# Plugin upgrade issue

Tags: plugins, customization, maintenance

I'm updating plugins installed on my wordpress site. However, for almost an hour, it's still doing maintenance mode. When I accidentally hit reload, I got BIG white screen of death saying: **"Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute."**

Is there anything I can do to fix this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[How to clear the "Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance" message after doing automatic upgrade?](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_clear_the_.22Briefly_unavailable_for_scheduled_maintenance.22_message_after_doing_automatic_upgrade.3F)**

> As part of the automatic upgrade
>   WordPress places a file named
>   `.maintenance` in the blog **base**
>   folder (folder that contains the
>   wp-admin folder). If that file exists,
>   then vistors will see the message
>   **Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute.**
>
> To stop that message from being
>   displayed to vistors, just delete the
>   `.maintenance` file. The automatic
>   upgrade should be executed again, just
>   in case it failed.