# How to check for completeness when upgrading fails and stuck in maintenance mode

Tags: plugins, upgrade

**Background**: I was upgrading multiple plugins and when the upgrade (backend) screen comes up, it does take some time to load (I am guessing that WP is fetching the upgrade files). For some reason (server location amongst others) this screen can take a while to come up, but once the upgrading process starts, it usually goes quickly and smoothly.

Every now and then I have a lapse in judgement and am too eager to continue my work and start clicking away, and usually I realise this and stop. But not today :)

I clicked off too early and got stuck in maintenance mode.

**Where I'm at**: I fixed the maintenance mode without an issue as per ([stuck in maintenance mode -- wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/30-stuck-in-maintenance-mode-after-failed-plugin-upgrade) and [plugin upgrade issue -- this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154/plugin-upgrade-issue)) but when I have gone back to the site, I have got no indication whether the plugins have successfully been upgraded or not.

As suggested in the second link above, I would like to run the update again but now all plugins are reported as being up to date.

**Question**: How can I be sure the update/upgrade completed successfully? I am concerned that it hasn't. These are significant plugins, would it be safe to uninstall them and reinstall (to be sure they are the latest versions)?

note: this is not a duplicate of the *unanswered* question: [What is a good way to test that plugin upgrades have completed properly?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159633/what-is-a-good-way-to-test-that-plugin-upgrades-have-completed-properly)

Comment: If it says all plugins are upto date that means WP was able to upgrade them successfully.

Comment: I have never checked that part of `core` or much of it at all really. I would suppose that the plugin update procedure would be pretty well defined (by now) but I would never like to assume it for fact. My concern is at what point are plugin versions updated. I'm hoping it is right after everything is complete, I am just not sure.

Comment: Plugin versions aren't saved in database. It is on the plugins main file at very top part. So, if you see updated plugin version that means WP was able to download the zip, extract and put new plugin files into the system.

Comment: @Sisir thanks, that's good to know. I will consider it done and dusted. If you want to convert this comment to an answer, I'd be happy to award a pretty green tick :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When WordPress shows themes/core/plugins are updated, it means they were successfully upgraded. Which means WP was able to download the zip, extract it then able to put/overwrite files into the file system.

WordPress does not save plugin/theme versions as a database entry they are directly read from plugin files and theme css. Theme/plugin/core bundle are served as a zip file. A partially downloaded zip files can not be extracted successfully because it will appear as a corrupt file.

*On the contrary*, there could be a possible scenario where WP was able to update the main plugin file or themes css file but not other files but I will assume possibilities of that happening is near zero. Write operation often fails when server doesn't have enough permission. If it can write one file it should be able to write all of em.

**That being said**, if you still want to make sure files are same as the WP repository. You can install the [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) plugin and do a scan. It can check current version of the plugin/theme/core to the WP repository (you will have to enable that option, it is not default) and tell you if anything missing or changed.